# How to fix NPM EJSONParse with this package.json file?

Tags: node.js, npm, command

when I try the command npm install I have this

```
C:\Users\khaou>npm install
npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE
npm ERR! path C:\Users\khaou/package.json    
npm ERR! JSON.parse Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing empty string
npm ERR! JSON.parse Failed to parse JSON data.
npm ERR! JSON.parse Note: package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\khaou\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-12-31T16_42_25_903Z-debug.log
```

This is the JSON:

```
{
  "name": "eth-todo-list",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Blockchain Todo List Powered By Ethereum",
  "main": "truffle-config.js",
  "directories": {
    "test": "test"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "lite-server",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && sexit 1"
  },
  "author": "gregory@dappuniversity.com",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "4.1.3",
    "chai": "^4.1.2",
    "chai-as-promised": "^7.1.1",
    "chai-bignumber": "^2.0.2",
    "lite-server": "^2.3.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.17.3",
    "truffle": "5.0.2",
    "truffle-contract": "3.0.6"
  }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're running `npm install` in your home directory.  Is that really where you intended to run it?  Your JSON is valid, so I suspect you're not running `npm install` in the right path.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your file association is other than JavaScript like JavaScript react or any other.

Check your `package.json` settings file to have `Item:javascript` `Value:javascript` as default extension (*) on `Files:Associations`.

```
package.json->file->preferences->settings->Files:Associations
Item:javascript Value:javascript
```

Hope it works!